# exec command with argument having % and ,

Tags: go

I need to run following command on Linux and get output using golang.

```
/bin/ps o pid,%cpu,%mem -p 14806
```

command works fine and produces result as follows:

```
  PID %CPU %MEM
14806  0.8  6.0
```

but it is not working via golang code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {

    cmd := exec.Command("ps", "o pid,%cpu,%mem -p 14806")
    fmt.Printf("Path: %q, args[1]: %q\n", cmd.Path, cmd.Args[1])

    out, err := exec.Command("ps", "o pid,%cpu,%mem -p 14806").Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("The date is %s\n", out)
}
```

**output**

```
Path: "/bin/ps", args[1]: "o pid,%cpu,%mem -p 14806"
2019/05/16 07:23:17 exit status 1
exit status 1
```

Comment: Each argument goes in its own string: `exec.Command("ps", "o", "pid,%cpu,%mem", "-p", "14806")`. This has _nothing_ to do with % signs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Volker

following code works

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {

    cmd := exec.Command("ps", "--no-headers", "o", "pid,%cpu,%mem", "-p", "14806")
    fmt.Printf("Path: %q, args[1]: %q\n", cmd.Path, cmd.Args[1])

    out, err := exec.Command("ps", "--no-headers", "o", "pid,%cpu,%mem", "-p", "14806").Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", out)
}
```